# How can I boot via USB with GA-945GCMNX-S2 BIOS?

Tags: boot, usb, bios

I'm using a computer with a Gigabyte GA-945GCMNX-S2.

So my issue here is the BIOS does detect the USB drive but does not boot in. I've tried Unetbootin, Live USB Installer and other tools but no luck.

The computer also has Windows XP but it didn't make the bootable USB successfully.

I've tried YUMI. The BiOS did recognize the USB as bootable in Hard Drive (USB-HDD0) but because it's YUMI there was an error (Missing operating system) I've even tried rebuild sysLinux in YUMI but it didn't work.

I have 2 USBs. One is 8GB and one is 16GB.

How can I boot into the USB with my BIOS?

And P/S: I do know the key thingy like [F12] and that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I... don't see a question here?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** What version of Ubuntu is your BIOS running?  (I.o.w. if your BIOS doesn't support USB booting, Ubuntu can't either)

Comment: @Fabby as I mentioned above v5.0 and BTW I can now be able to boot using PLoP Boot Manager.

Comment: Did you [verify the integrity](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) of the boot image? Can you boot from the USB drive with other machines? Is USB support enabled in BIOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've found my answer: PLoP Boot Manager. For who don't have a CD they will need one but for me I have built-in MS-DOS which is really helpful. I boot up my old Windows and copied the PLoP Boot Manager extracted to `C:/` and renamed for easier typing.

After that I booted into MS-DOS (via Windows Boot Manager) and `cd` into the `install` directory, ran `plpinst.com` then fully installed the PLoP boot manager. Since then I can be able to boot into USB whenever I want and also force the BIOS to do so.

Link to PLoP Boot Manager: https://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/download.html

P/S: FreeDOS is ok.

Comment: Good one!  Upvoted!  ;-)